# Eclipse and Salesforce

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, apex-code

I am working on Salesforce using the Eclipse IDE, I just want to access a simple currency converter webservice wsdl. http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL
my question is can we use the eclipse webservice client for wsdl which generates the classes for wsdl, and can we use those classes in salesforce then??

Comment: I've put an answer to this question in your Salesforce.StackExchange question.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11307/102

Answer (score 1):

you can directly convert WSDL to Apex classes in Salesforce.
- log into Salesforce.
- Navigate to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on button- Generate from WSDL.

Note: If WSDL contains more than 1 porttype, then that wsdl can't be Converted to Apex classes. May be Salesforce will leverage this functionality in later release.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Navigate to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on button- Generate from WSDL.** download the wsdl file.
Download wsc from [here](https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/downloads/detail?name=wsc-22.jar)
You can use the salesforce wsc jar to generate required java classes.

Use this command to generate the jar file.

java -classpath location_of_jar\wsc-22.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc  wsdl_location\enterprise.wsdl salesforce.jar

All the classes will be bundled into the salesforce.jar. Add that as a lib to your eclipse project.